# Conditional PHP Code Not Accepting Values

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have the following PHP code that doesn't seem to work properly in the conditional part.  I am able to properly get the inputs from the user for the three sides of the triangle, but the IF statement is not doing what it's supposed to be doing - any ideas??

```
<?php

echo "Thank you for the input.  ";
echo "You entered in the following values: ".$_GET["firstSide"].", ".$_GET["secondSide"],", and ".$_GET["thirdSide"]." "; 


$int_firstSide = @$_GET["firstSide"];
$int_secondSide = @$_GET["secondSide"];
$int_thirdSide = @$_GET["thirdSide"];

$oneAndtwo = $int_firstSide + $int_secondSide;
$oneAndthree = $int_firstSide + $int_thirdSide;
$twoAndthree = $int_secondSide + $int_thirdSide;

if((($oneAndtwo) > ($int_thirdSide)) || (($oneAndthree) > ($int_secondSide)) || (($twoAndthree) > ($int_firstSide)))
{
    echo "  Based on the entered values, you indeed have a Triangle...";
} else {
   echo "You do not have a valid Triangle...Sorry...have a nice day and thanks for playing!";
}


?>
```

Comment: Please explain what is supposed to do and what it is actually doing

Comment: Please give us an example of the  $_GET content

Comment: it's supposed to print out a valid triangle based on the inputs - for instance, 3, 4, 5 would indicate a valid triangle, but in this case, 1,2,3 is also showing a valid triangle, when it should not.

Comment: _$GET is from another page from a form.  Here is the html:<html>
<body>

<form action="solver_get.php" method="get">
First Side: <input type="text" name="firstSide"><br>
Second Side: <input type="text" name="secondSide"><br>
Third Side: <input type="text" name="thirdSide"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>

Comment: As a side note, you're way overusing parentheses in the `if` statement. None of them are necessary (apart from the ones part of the construct of course). Also, suppressing errors and warnings with the `@` prefix is not generally advisable. Lastly, your variable naming is a little off, seeing as none of the variables called `$int_` are actually ints (they're all strings). If you really need an `int` (which you don't), then you can prefix the variables with a `+` or with an explicit cast to `(int)`.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working by replacing the or with and in the above.